# Modified distance functions for a cluster analysis

Tags: clustering, data-transformation, outliers, distance-functions

I'm developing some software to allow users to perform various kinds of clustering on some data using a pairwise distance matrix (k-medoids is the main method). I would like to allow the user to tune a parameter `p` that changes how sensitive the method is to outliers, and I've found a particular log transformation of the distances `d` that is doing what I want, at least when `p = 20`: `y = log_10(p*d + 1)`. It acts to "suppress" large values, such that the algorithm differentiates little between medium and large distances; IE the penalty to include an outlier in a cluster is lessened.

However, no matter the value of p the function never approaches the original distances. I want the clustering to be performed on the regular distances when `p` is at its "resting" value (maybe 1, maybe 0, depending on the transformation function used), and I want the clustering to be less and less sensitive to outliers as `p` is set further and further from this resting value.

Does anyone have a suggestion for such a transformation? Distances will always be positive, but can be very small and can be zero. I don't care if the function has a horizontal asymptote or not; I'm not particularly fussy beyond the idea that it approaches no transformation at some particular value.

Below is a little mock-up graph showing what I'm looking for. The dotted line is no transformation (`p = 1`), and the suppression becomes more extreme as `p` is increased to 4.

[image: Mock graph]

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across this and is interested, the function I ended up using was:

`y = (p*d + 1)^(1/p) - 1`

This works to change the behavior of my clustering, such that outliers are more permissible in clusters when `p > 1`.